# How do you do a 3d plot in pgf plots if your 3d data set format has an x and y value that is separate from the z-value

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am aware I didn't explain the problem in the title sufficiently, but I have this particular problem where I am unable to plot my 3d data set in pgfplots. Most data sets on the pgf plots are formated like this

```
x   y   z
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
```

where a,b, and c are values of the x, y, and z. However, my data set looks something like this

```
    a   a   a   a
b   c   c   c   c 
b   c   c   c   c
b   c   c   c   c
b   c   c   c   c
```

Where the value c has the corresponding x-value at a column and y-value at the row. How does one plot this? Do I really need to convert it into the first format? I am dealing with a spreadsheet about 1000 rows and 1000 columns wide, doing that would be tedious. How would one plot this kind of 3d data set in pgfplots?

Perhaps something like this would be a more concrete example. This is simply $x^2+y^2$ but in the same data format

```
    -10 -8  -6  -4  -2  0   2   4   6   8   10
-10 200 164 136 116 104 100 104 116 136 164 200
-8  164 128 100 80  68  64  68  80  100 128 164
-6  136 100 72  52  40  36  40  52  72  100 136
-4  116 80  52  32  20  16  20  32  52  80  116
-2  104 68  40  20  8   4   8   20  40  68  104
0   100 64  36  16  4   0   4   16  36  64  100
2   104 68  40  20  8   4   8   20  40  68  104
4   116 80  52  32  20  16  20  32  52  80  116
6   136 100 72  52  40  36  40  52  72  100 136
8   164 128 100 80  68  64  68  80  100 128 164
10  200 164 136 116 104 100 104 116 136 164 200
```